# How to adjust a floated div to be top right

Tags: html, css

So I am going to be working with Php and summing values up so I need the last div to be generated after all the other divs are.

Is there a way to align the last div (Div #4) with the top right of the beige box? My issue is I have to place it right below or above Div #1 in order for it to float right properly, but I want to place it after Div #3 and still have it float right but float at the top of the beige box.

Essentially what I am trying to do is get the green box to be in the top right of the beige box, but with having the html code for it after Div #3.

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:1000px; background-color: peachpuff">
  <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: purple; float:left">
    <div>Div 1</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: pink; float:left">
    <div>Div 2</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: red; float:left">
    <div>Div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:20%;height:600px;background-color: green; float:right">
    <div>Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try display:inline-flex; in parent div and add clear:left; to divs alinged to left... this has worked for me at somepoint?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird stuff to wanna make this this way. Here is what you can do :

```
<div style="width:100%;height:1000px; background-color: peachpuff">
        <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: purple; float:left"><!--  Div #1  -->
            <div>Div 1</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: pink; float:left"><!--  Div #2  -->
            <div>Div 2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: red; float:left"><!--  Div #3  -->
            <div>Div 3</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:20%;height:600px;background-color: green; margin-left: 10%;"> <!--  Div #4  -->
            <div>Div 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Take off your `float: right`. It'll stuck the left floating blocks on the right. Then you set the left blocks to 70% width, your right block to 20%, so 70 - 20 = 10% staying. Add a `margin-left: 10%;` and the job is done.

Comment: Tried it and the green box ended up going under the 3rd div on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `float:right` from last `div` and use `margin-left` which will be `100%-width`

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:1000px; background-color: peachpuff">
  <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: purple; float:left">
    <div>Div 1</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: pink; float:left">
    <div>Div 2</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: red; float:left">
    <div>Div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:20%;height:600px;background-color: green;margin-left:80%;">
    <div>Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you are allowed to change some markup, try to wrap `left` and `right` boxes in different div

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:1000px; background-color: peachpuff;">
  <div style="width:70%;float:left;">
    <div style="height:140px;background-color: purple;">
      <div>Div 1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:140px;background-color: pink;">
      <div>Div 2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:140px;background-color: red;">
      <div>Div 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;width:20%;">
    <div style="height:600px;background-color: green;">
      <div>Div 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div style="width:100%;height:1000px; background-color: peachpuff">
    <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: purple; float:left"><!--  Div #1  -->
        <div>Div 1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:20%;height:420px;background-color: green;float: right"> <!--  Div #4  -->
        <div>Div 4</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: pink; float:left"><!--  Div #2  -->
        <div>Div 2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:70%;height:140px;background-color: red; float:left"><!--  Div #3  -->
        <div>Div 3</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need the Div #4 to be after all the other ones, it will have some Php calculations prior.